# "message": "Call to a member function currentAccessToken() on null",

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-sanctum, laravel-jetstream

I have a logout function (to revoke the token), but when I fill in the Authorization headers with Bearer 6|4dc2p1jSWxXVdHPL8vHFK1x7SPSFysl0nOcVH78Ye3c75982 in Postman, it returns the response 'message': 'Call to a member function currentAccessToken() on null'. How can I resolve this?

my UserController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Helpers\ResponseFormatter;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    ...

    /**
     * Logout a user by revoking the current access token.
     *
     * @param Request $request The HTTP request
     * @throws Some_Exception_Class description of exception
     * @return Some_Return_Value
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $token=$request->User()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
        return ResponseFormatter::success($token, 'Token Revoked');
    }
}
```

my routes/api.php:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductCategoryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Rules\Role;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function(){
    Route::get('user',[UserController::class,'fetch']);
    Route::post('user',[UserController::class,'updateProfile']);});
    Route::post('logout',[UserController::class,'logout']);

Route::get('products',[ProductController::class,'all']);
Route::get('categories',[ProductCategoryController::class,'all']);
Route::post('register',[UserController::class,'register']);
Route::post('login',[UserController::class,'login']);
```

my postman:
[postman resnponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAUxV.png)

I want to be able to revoke/delete the token directly when I input it into Postman

Comment: It sounds In your `UserController`, `$request->User()` is null. try `auth('sanctum')->user()` instead. (before logout, check if current user is present, with `auth('sanctum')->check()`)

Comment: one more thing, Shouldn't the letter ‍`u‍‍‍` in the `$request->User()` be in lowercase letters?